# How do I open android projects using emacs ede

Tags: android-ndk, adk, cedet

The emacs documentation http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ede.html#Android-projects mentions that global-ede-mode supports android projects.

It mentions a function to declare the android sdk location, which I cannot find in emacs.
It also mentions that ede includes tools to interface with android tools, such as build and run emulators. These tools I cannot find either.

Has anybody had any luck using emacs built in ede mode to access android projects?

Currently running lubuntu 14.04 with emacs 24.3.1

Answer (score 0):

The Android support for EDE is part of the CEDET project at http://cedet.sf.net, but that part wasn't included during the last merge from the CEDET repository into Emacs.  Apparently that support wasn't removed form the manual. :)

If you download the sources from bzr, you will discover `lisp/cedet/cedet-android.el`, and `lisp/cedet/ede/android.el` which is the the support you found described in the manual.

In theory, you might be able to pull those two files down from bzr and just add to your own lisp repository, though it is always safest to download the entirety of the CEDET code and use it's install mechanism to ensure everything works correctly.

Once installed, you will find that the Development menu as project and target options that list things like starting up the debugger, or easily navigating between different .xml sources and your java source.